# How to determine when user scrolls to bottom of container div? For Infinite Scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, infinite-scroll

I'm preparing to develop infinate scroll on our website's dashboard, however I'm stuck at the moment on how to determine the bottom of the container div in my [jsfiddle mockup](http://jsfiddle.net/leonwho/L9A6Q/).

[image]

Original function, which works on a blank page with no container div

```
var wireInfinScroll = function() {

    console.log('in wireInfinScroll');

    $('#scroll_screen').scroll(function(){

        console.log('scrolling...');
        console.log(' ');

        //if ($('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() == $('#content').height() -     $('#scroll_screen').outerHeight()) {
  
        if ($('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() == $('#content').height() - $('#scroll_screen').height()) {
            // run our call for pagination
            console.log('Bottom of Page!');
            alert('Bottom of Page!');
        }
    });
}

wireInfinScroll();
```

CSS

```
#scroll_screen {
  overflow-y: auto;
  background: pink;
}
```

I tried replacing `window` with the div being scrolled (`#scroll_screen`) in my example, but can't get the alert to trigger.

How would you have approached this problem?

---

**UPDATES**

- Note, I created a new jsFiddle using the same code here:
  http://jsfiddle.net/leonwho/L9A6Q/
- Also I notice that my console.logs never show unless I click inside
  the `#scroll_screen` div?
- Deleted the Codepen, got a little further with jsFiddle, using `$('#scroll_screen').scroll(function(){`
- Note! When I remove `height: 100%` from the `#content` div, then scroll down and back up I finally get my **Alert**, but this is still not correct. The **Alert** should happen on scroll down

css

```
   #content {
     float: right;
     width: 79%;
     //height: 100%;
     background: #f8f8f8;
   }
```

Comment: `$(window).height() - $(window).height()` will always be 0

Comment: Ah sorry, originally it was window.scrollTop == document.height - window.height

Comment: There is nothing on that link, do you mind using Fiddle, which is more reliable, because I think I know the answer! (Not what was posted)

Comment: @LeonGaban  I need to see your CSS, I saw something like `100%` on body, so I need to see if removing that works.  Also, there were a bunch of errors in your HTML.

Comment: Added new Notes and just created the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/leonwho/L9A6Q/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$('#scroll_screen').height() - $('#content').height()` will give a negative value, because `scroll_screen`'s height is always less than `content`'s height, and that means `scroll_screen`'s `scrollTop` will never be equal to a negative value, so replace

```
$('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() == $('#scroll_screen').height() - $('#content').height()
```

with

```
$('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() >=  if ( $('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() >= -($('#content').height() - $('#scroll_screen').height()) ))
```

(Greater than or equal just in-case the animation skips it.)

[EDIT] I noticed it scrolls to `200`, so `if ($('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() >= 200)` should work.

Comment: Using the `>=` now the Alert will activate all the time because the first half of that equation will always be true http://jsfiddle.net/leonwho/L9A6Q/ would you mind a jsfiddle fork example?

Comment: @LeonGaban Here's a small fix (try it): `if ($('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() >= 200)`

Comment: I got it! Just had to use `-()` to reverse the value `if ( $('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() >= -($('#content').height() - $('#scroll_screen').height()) ) {`

Comment: @LeonGaban Glad to here it, but since `if ($('#scroll_screen').scrollTop() >= 200)` also works, do you mind accepting my answer ;)  Also, I added your fix.  PS: Thanks, glad to help

Comment: accepted, I'm seeing another potential problem with the height of content, but I have enough to go forward now, thanks!

Comment: @LeonGaban Your welcome, but if you still need help with something, post a Collaboration link on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

You just have to check if (the scroll distance + the window height) >= (the offset top of the element + its height) in your scroll method.

In this case, something like :

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
  if( ($(document).scrollTop() + $(window).height()) >= ($('#yourElement').offset().top + $('#yourElement').height()){
    // Bottom of the element reached :)
  }
});
```